# positioning html image same as with css

Tags: jquery, html, css

Is it possible to make the same thing like this with *HTML*, because I want to make it with `<img>` not with `background` property.

What can exactly replace the `background-size`, `position` etc ?

```
   .post-img {
       width: 380px;
       height: 380px;
       border-radius: 100%;
       -webkit-border-radius: 100%;
       -moz-border-radius: 100%;
       background: url(../images/dsc_0016.jpg) no-repeat;
       background-position: center;
       background-size: cover;
    }
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I remember I had a same question a while ago. That's why I give a quick answer.

But ***you should always provide code with what you tried first***.

Just create a div `img-container` with the dimensions you want. Place your image inside that div.

```
<div class="img-container">
    <img src="path/to/image">
</div>
```

Then add the CSS:

```
.img-container {
    height: 380px;
    width: 380px;
}

.img-container img {
    display: block;
    height: auto;
    max-height: auto;
    width: 100%;
 }
```

Something like that should do the job. Might need a little tweeking. But that should give you an idea how to do it...